# Flutter: dart:html and 'WebSocket' not found when I'm trying to run myapp

Tags: flutter, dart

My app was working perfectly fine, but I didn't know what exactly happened and this error has been showing now. I've tried to clean the cache, also run flutter clean and delete build but always appears:*

```dart
/C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/get-4.6.6/lib/get_connect/sockets/src/sockets_html.dart:4:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:html' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:html';
       ^
Context: The unavailable library 'dart:html' is imported through these packages:

   package:ecommapptest => package:get => dart:html

Detailed import paths for (some of) the these imports:

package:ecommapptest/main.dart => package:ecommapptest/views/introduction_screen.page.dart => package:ecommapptest/views/apphomepage.dart => package:ecommapptest/views/uicomponents/drawercontent.dart => package:ecommapptest/views/uicomponents/profile.dart => package:ecommapptest/views/testphp/testnavigationlist.dart => package:get/get_connect/sockets/src/sockets_html.dart => dart:html

/C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/get-4.6.6/lib/get_connect/sockets/src/sockets_html.dart:11:3: Error: Type 'WebSocket' not found.
  WebSocket? socket;
  ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/get-4.6.6/lib/get_connect/sockets/src/sockets_html.dart:11:3: Error: 'WebSocket' isn't a type.
  WebSocket? socket;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check in your project dart files you have mistakenly imported sockets_html.dart in your code just remove that and it will work.

Answer (score -1):

Solved:
So to help others who might face the same problem.
The problem was provoked when I accidentally ran my project ( with Get library ) on Chrome instead of my Emulator.
To solve the problem, find the sockets_html.dart and just commented all it's content. and it worked perfectly.